# How to set a picture with caption in table?

Tags: tables, floats, captions

[image]

How to set caption for images in table?  like this image.

Comment: You can use `\captionof{figure}{your actual caption}` (by packages `capt-of` and `caption` as well as any KOMA-class) to do this, but why? Let the figures float around.

Comment: In case the above didn't help you already, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5):

You haven't provided your requirements for quite a few design aspects, so I have to make some assumptions. In particular, in the examples below I'll assume that the two side-by-side figures should jointly span the entire width of the text block.

You also haven't indicated whether or not the side-by-side figures should be able to float, in the LaTeX sense of the word. I'll provide suggestions for both cases:

- If you want the two side-by-side figures to be able to float (while staying next to each other, of course), set up a `figure` environment that encases two `minipage` environments. Each `minipage` could be as wide as `0.48\textwidth`, say. Inside each `minipage`, use an `\includegraphics` instruction (with the width of the graph set to `1\linewidth`) to load the images of interest. As usual, use `\caption` and `\label` statements, but now within a `minipage`, to create the captions and set up a means for cross-referencing the `figures`.
- If you do *not* want the side-by-side figures to float, change the preceding setup as follows:

  - Remove the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` statements, but do keep the `minipage`-related statements. If you want the two minipages to span the width of the text block, be sure to provide a `\noindent` statement right before the first one.
  - Replace the `\caption{...}` statements with `\captionof{figure}{...}` statements. You need to load the `caption` package to get access to the  `\captionof` macro. Keep using `\label` statements as before.

  That's all there is to it. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption} % for \captionof macro
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
Here's a cross-reference to Figure~\ref{fig:star2}.

\hrule % just to illustrate the width of the text block

%% a floating version
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{first.pdf}
\caption{A cloud} \label{fig:cloud1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{second.pdf}
\caption{A star} \label{fig:star1}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

%% a non-floating version
\noindent %  override any \parindent effect
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{third.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Another cloud} \label{fig:cloud2}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fourth.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Another star} \label{fig:star2}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

The title of your posting actually was, "How to set a picture with caption in *table*?" (emphasis added) You may be wondering why I have so far *not* mentioned a method that involves a table-like structure. It turns out that one *could* -- but I would strongly argue that one *should not* -- lift the code that generates figures 3 and 4 above and place it inside a `tabular*` environment (and replace `\hspace{\fill}` with `&`):

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r @{}}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fifth.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Still another cloud} \label{fig:cloud3}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{sixth.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{Still another star} \label{fig:star3}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular*}
```

You may verify for yourself that this code produces the exact same output as the earlier, also non-floating, code. I hope you can convince yourself that incurring the extra overhead generated by encasing the two `minipage` environments inside a `tabular*` environment is pointless and undesirable.